# c# Seamless OAuth2 OWIN Token Based Authentication Web API to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I have a mobile app that uses WebAPI backed by OWIN to authenticate users. Logging in returns a token that is then reused when subsequent API calls are made.

### The problem

I want to create a web page that is MVC based, which can authenticate the user (via the token) seamlessly.

Comment: Not sure if that is possible OOB. But I did end up using both `token` for mobile and `cookie` based for web in the same project. Are you opening this MVC webpage inside your mobile app ?

Comment: Yes that's right. I just want authentication to flow from the app to the webpage